# SQL create table with filters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have an autogenerated create table SQL statement from the import/export wizard. However, the the table I am creating from has too many rows, therefore I would like to import only after a certain date.

I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [DB1].[dbo].[Agent] (
[UserId] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
[StatusDateTime] datetime NOT NULL,
[StatusDateTimeGMT] datetime NOT NULL,
) where StatusDateTimeGMT >='2011-08-15'
```

When I try to add either a where clause with the `StatusDateTimeGMT` field being >='2011-08-15', it throws me an error. I also tried using a CHECK constraint, but with no success. Any ideas?

Here is the error:

> Error 0xc002f210: Preparation SQL Task: Executing the query
>   "CREATE TABLE [db1].[dbo].[Agent] (
>       [UserId] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
>       [StatusDateTime] datetime NOT NULL,
>       [StatusDateTimeGMT] datetime NOT NULL,
>       )where StatusDateTimeGMT >='20110815'  "
>   failed with the following error: "Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040E14". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

Comment: Did you try without the dashes, e.g. >= '20110815'?

Comment: Just tried, didn't help.

Comment: Maybe include the *actual* error message rather than just "an error" and a screen shot that shows where you're trying to add this where clause.

Comment: You can't just chuck "where StatusDateTimeGMT >='20110815'" after the `create table` and expect it to work! Maybe create a view with your desired filter then export from that.

Comment: Table creation, and data importation are 2 separate tasks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if understood the question, but if you want to load the data that matches a certain parameter, you first create the table and then insert the data you want in it using a command similar to the following.

```
INSERT INTO [BD1].[dbo].[Agent]
SELECT [UserId], [StatusDateTime], [StatusDateTimeGMT] 
FROM [sourceData]
WHERE StatusDateTimeGMT >='2011-08-15'
```

Just as an example.

Comment: I tried this in my SSIS package, but I was getting a unicode converison error, where from what I have read, is fixed by using the wizard instead.

Comment: You should have mentioned that you're using SSIS. For that type of error problably you are not reading the data from source with the right type. What type of source file you're reading from?

Comment: From a different DB in a separate server.

Comment: So you define in SSIS a OLEDB Provider to the source data, create the table to hold the data, and then import the data applying the filter you want.

Comment: Using this method, I am given unicode conversion errors on every field I am trying to import.

Comment: Check if the datatypes from the source match the ones from the table you are creating, if not correct it or do some type conversions in SSIS, risking to truncate some data.